# TLS 1.2 in Spring boot with Jetty Embeded

Tags: ssl, openssl, spring-boot, jetty, tls1.2

I have to fix some penetration test issues.
One of them is Upgrade to TLS v1.2.

My app is a spring boot application that runs on the embedded Jetty server. 
(8443 is my ssl.port)
So to test this, when i run:

- *openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443*
  i get:

**Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(00000550)
10420:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:.\ssl\s23_lib.c:188:**

But when run:

- *openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -tls1*  
  (basically forcing to use tsl v1) i get:

**SSL-Session: 

    Protocol  : TLSv1 

    Cipher    : EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA**

(among lots of other things ofcourse).

So this means that my jetty only supports tls v1.

How can i get it to run with tls 1.2? I know that spring boot should support TLS 1.2 by default.

Comment: What version of Jetty (Recommend Jetty 9.2+)?  What version of Java (Recommend Java 8+)?

Comment: Jetty version: jetty-9.2.11.v201505297. And the jdk is 1.8.0_65.